# Query MongoDB ISO date between two dates in Perl

Tags: perl, mongodb, isodate

I am working with [`MongoDB`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB) and am not having an easy time trying to add the *less-than* to my working `$gte` query. The below query works when I remove the `$lt` line from it.

I am trying to get records between two dynamic dates - minutes. That does work for `$gte`, but introducing the `$lt` gives me nothing.

I validated the variables for the dates are correct.  Am I overcomplicating this?

Perl code:

```
my $cursor = $collection->find({
    create_date => {
        '$gte' => DateTime->new(
            year   => $dtpast_year,
            month  => $dtpast_month,
            day    => $dtpast_day,
            hour   => $dtpast_hour,
            minute => $dtpast_minute
        ),
        '$lt' => DateTime->new(
            year => $dtpresent_year,
            month  => $dtpresent_month,
            day    => $dtpresent_day,
            hour   => $dtpresent_hour,
            minute => $dtpresent_minute
        )
    }
});
```

I cleaned it up a bit with the same issue.  I will

```
my $present = DateTime->new(
    year   => $dtpresent_year,
    month  => $dtpresent_month,
    day    => $dtpresent_day,
    hour   => $dtpresent_hour,
    minute => $dtpresent_minute
);
my $past = DateTime->new(
    year   => $dtpast_year,
    month  => $dtpast_month,
    day    => $dtpast_day,
    hour   => $dtpast_hour,
    minute => $dtpast_minute
);

my $cursor = $collection->find({create_date => {'$gte' => $past}});
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. Can you get it to work with just the `$lt` filter? I suggest you create the two `DateTime` objects as separate variables and print `$start->iso8601` and `$end->iso8601` to make sure you've got what you think you have. Then the filter will be just `create_date => { '$gte' => $start, '$lt' => $end }`

Comment: Yes.  It works with just one, but not both.

Comment: RESENT:2015-05-07T11:50:00
PAST:2015-05-07T11:50:00

Comment: Those date-times are identical. No value can be *both* greater than or equal to *and* less than that

Comment: looks like I found my issue.  PRESENT:2015-05-07T11:56:00
PAST:   2015-05-07T11:56:00  They are the same time for some reason.

Comment: mark the issue as solved?